# python 3, pandas and creating new columns fail with keyerror

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I've been using the apply method on a dataframe to create new columns. So, if I have a df that looks like this:

```
stdf.columns
Index(['Username', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Class', 'Screens Typed','Time Spent', 'Avg Speed', 'Avg Acc'],  dtype='object')
```

I've be using syntax like this to create new columns

```
stdf['uid'] = stdf['Username'].apply(lambda x: x[0:6]) + "-" + stdf['First Name'] + "-" + stdf['Last Name']
```

Today when using that same method to create a new column I get a keyerror on the new column name

```
stdf['truSpeed'] = stdf['nSpeed'].apply(lambda x: x * .1 * stdf["truAcc"])
```

yes, 'nSpeed' and 'truAcc' do exist as columns.

```
Index(['Username', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Class', 'Screens Typed', 'Time Spent', 'Avg Speed', 'Avg Acc', 'truTime', 'uid', 'truAcc',
```

'nSpeed'], dtype='object')

The keyerror points to the 'truSpeed identifier.
So my question is why is pandas now telling me I have a keyerror when trying to create a new column when it has always created the new column in the past?

There must be some other error that I'm not seeing.

Here's the almost full traceback

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/david/dev/msc/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2133             try:
-> 2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2135             except KeyError:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)()

KeyError: 'truSpeed'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/david/dev/msc/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in set(self, item, value, check)
   3667         try:
-> 3668             loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3669         except KeyError:

/home/david/dev/msc/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2135             except KeyError:
-> 2136                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2137 

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)()

KeyError: 'truSpeed'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-35d20ff4edf0> in <module>()
      4 stdf['nSpeed'] = stdf['Avg Speed'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split(" ")[0]))
      5 print(stdf.columns)
----> 6 stdf['truSpeed'] = stdf['nSpeed'].apply(lambda x: x * .1 * stdf["truAcc"])
      7 # stdf['truSpeed']
      8 # print(stdf.columns)

/home/david/dev/msc/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2417         else:
   2418             # set column
-> 2419             self._set_item(key, value)
   2420 
   2421     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

/home/david/dev/msc/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   2484         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
   2485         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
-> 2486         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   2487 
   2488         # check if we are modifying a copy

/home/david/dev/msc/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   1498 
   1499     def _set_item(self, key, value):
-> 1500         self._data.set(key, value)
   1501         self._clear_item_cache()
   1502 

/home/david/dev/msc/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in set(self, item, value, check)
   3669         except KeyError:
   3670             # This item wasn't present, just insert at end
-> 3671             self.insert(len(self.items), item, value)
   3672             return
   3673 

/home/david/dev/msc/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in insert(self, loc, item, value, allow_duplicates)
   3770 
   3771         block = make_block(values=value, ndim=self.ndim,
-> 3772                            placement=slice(loc, loc + 1))
   3773 
   3774         for blkno, count in _fast_count_smallints(self._blknos[loc:]):

/home/david/dev/msc/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in make_block(values, placement, klass, ndim, dtype, fastpath)
   2683                      placement=placement, dtype=dtype)
   2684 
-> 2685     return klass(values, ndim=ndim, fastpath=fastpath, placement=placement)
   2686 
   2687 # TODO: flexible with index=None and/or items=None

/home/david/dev/msc/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim, fastpath)
    107             raise ValueError('Wrong number of items passed %d, placement '
    108                              'implies %d' % (len(self.values),
--> 109                                              len(self.mgr_locs)))
    110 
    111     @property

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 58, placement implies 1
```

Comment: I got this error when I tried to assign a subset of the frame instead of a series ```df['new_col'] = df[df['some_col']=='SomeValue']```

Answer (score 2):

```
stdf['truSpeed'] = stdf['nSpeed'].apply(lambda x: x * .1 * stdf["truAcc"])
```

Should be

```
stdf['truSpeed'] = stdf.eval('nSpeed * truAcc * .1')
```

Or

```
stdf['truSpeed'] = stdf['nSpeed'] * stdf['truAcc'] * .1
```

Or the slow way with

```
stdf['truSpeed'] = stdf.apply(lambda x: x['nSpeed'] * x['truAcc'] * .1, axis=1)
```

Comment: piRSquare: THANK you. the df.eval syntax is new to me. I guess I may have been looking at older pandas documentation. The old slow way at the end of the list still through the keyerror. I am guessing now that there is a different exception that is being through and the keyerror is obscuring it. I realized after looking at the apply lambda syntax that I don't need the lambda.. I think my brain was stuck in an r-data frame like paradigm - the third syntax you gave above worked exactly as I needed it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to piRSquared there is an easier syntax. As mentioned in the comment, the df.eval syntax is new and it worked. However, the syntax that seems to 'fit' the paradigm that excel spreadsheets use is the third syntax

```
stdf['truSpeed'] = stdf['nSpeed'] * stdf['truAcc'] * .1
```

I think the keyerror originally generated must have been caused by some other error since using the identifier 'truSpeed' works just find to create the new column in the data frame.